# Find the childs of an object using ng-click in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<li class="company-area" >
     <div ng-click="showJobs($event)" >
            <div class="title"><br>Some stuff</div>
                  <div class="details" style="display: none;">
                     Some other stuff
             </div>
       </div>
</li>
```

I want when the user clicks on that are to show the details. I have a function on a controller:

```
 $scope.showJobs = function(evt){
        console.log(evt.target);
     }
```

The problem is that when I click it it prints only the title class, I want its parent and all the childs including the title and the details class. I cannot understand where is the mistake since the ng-click is on the outer div. Any help?

Comment: Try with `$event.currentTarget` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `evt.currentTarget` to get the div where `ng-click` is defined, and all it's children.

`evt.currentTarget` is the element the event listener is created on.

`evt.target` is the element that triggered the event (so depends on where you click).